# Pass data-parameters from parent to child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to implementing an onClick handler for a div element. The parent div has data parameters present while the child divs do not have anything. When i clicked the children divs the onlick handler was being called but no data-parameters were present. And if i click the parent element then i could find the data-parameters. My question is if onclick action can be passed to the child elements how to do the same for data elements?

When i click the parent elements the log i get:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "id1": "2",
 "id3": "3"
}
```

When i click the child elements the log i get:

```
{}
```

Below is my code

```js
$('.base_div').click(function(ev){console.log(ev.target.dataset);})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="content-box base_div" data-id="1" data-id1="2" data-id3="3" style="padding: 30px;">
  <div>
      Child Element 1
  </div>
  <div class="test_class">
      Child Element 2
  </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The child elements don't have a dataset! What did you expect?

Comment: I expected that when the parent div click was being handled by the child elements, the data parameters should come, which does not come through though. If i could i can place the data parameters inside the child elements also but i wanted to achieve it without cluttering the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `ev.target` with `ev.currentTarget` since `event.currentTarget` always **refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached**.

`event.target` identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Or you can simply replace `ev.target` with `this`.

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

```js
$('.base_div').click(function(ev){console.log(ev.currentTarget.dataset);})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="content-box base_div" data-id="1" data-id1="2" data-id3="3" style="padding: 30px;">
  <div>
      Child Element 1
  </div>
  <div class="test_class">
      Child Element 2
  </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yeah that does it. It was simple should have looked at the other elements being returned. Thanks for helping!